# How can I add a url (live chat) in a vuejs website?

Tags: vue.js

I've tried different kinds of embeds on my website but it doesnt seem to work. Can I still add a url and show it inside a vuejs website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can use. The approach is iframe tag as

```
<iframe
src="url of live chat"></iframe>
```

Please use it

Comment: Right after I saw an article about it! Thanks!